# Forwarding activity result to parent, with singleTop launch mode

Tags: android

I have two activities:  a MainListActivity, and a DetailViewActivity.  DetailViewActivity is set with `android:launchMode="singleTop"`.

When clicking an item in the "main list" activity, it launches the "detail view" activity via:

```
startActivityForResult(detailIntent, REQUEST_CODE_DETAIL);
```

If I then call `setResult(RESULT_OK, resultData);` and `finish();` from within the Detail activity, that resultData is received by the "main list" activity's `onActivityResult(..)` method correctly.

However, if I implement a "see previous"/"see next" type of navigation within the Detail activity, and implement it using singleTop, that result no longer gets sent back to the initial activity:

```
Intent nextItemIntent = this.createIntent(nextId);
nextItemIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
startActivity(nextItemIntent);
// at this point, my DetailActivity's onNewIntent() method is called, and the new data is loaded properly
```

But from here, when I call `setResult(..)` and `finish()`, my MainList activity never receives the new/updated result.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bah...  my mistake.  Looks like the problem was `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT`.  Apparently that flag is *not* needed when using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and `onNewIntent(..)`..  So by setting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT`, I was actually telling Android to forward my result data one activity farther back on the stack (activity before MainListActivity).

I removed that flag, and it now works as expected:

```
Intent nextItemIntent = this.createIntent(nextId);
nextItemIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(nextItemIntent);
```

And all is well.